# Insert nVarchar value into Bigint field

Tags: sql-server

I want to insert `NVARCHAR(255)` value which is a decimal value (115.11) from one table in a `BIGINT` field of another table.

I also should be using a formula like (Column1 * 100) before I insert in the `BIGINT` Field.

```
SELECT  CAST(Column1 AS BIGINT)
  FROM  Table1
  WHERE ISNUMERIC(Column1) = 1
```

The above query still shows conversion error.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This multiplicand for 100

```
SELECT CAST(CAST (Column1  AS FLOAT)*100 AS BIGINT) from Table1 where ISNUMERIC(Column1)=1
```

this truncating the decimals

```
SELECT CAST(CAST (Column1  AS FLOAT) AS BIGINT) from Table1 where ISNUMERIC(Column1)=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CAST (CAST (NVarCharCol AS decimal(9,2)) * 100 AS BIGINT) from YourTable where ISNUMERIC(NVarCharCol)=1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.Appreciate it!